# entityframework Inherited classes in single table can not use timestamp?

Tags: entity-framework, timestamp

I want to create a TimeStamp field in Inherited class like this:

```
[Table("TABLE_A")]
public class A
{
  public int ID {get;set;}

  public string Name {get;set;}
}

[Table("TABLE_B")]
public class B : A
{
  public string Address {get;set;}

  [TimeStamp]
  public byte[] RowVersion {get;set;}
}
```

but failed, how can I do here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will see error

> Type 'B' defines new concurrency requirements that are not allowed for
>   subtypes of base EntitySet types.

That means exactly what error says. Entity Framework do not support concurrency checks in derived types. You will see same error if you'll add simple concurrency check instead of timestamp:

```
[Table("TABLE_B")]
public class B : A
{
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

If you will move concurrency checking to base class, then it will work, but only on base type. If you need checking to be performed on derived type, I think you should use Stored Procedure for updating entity.